# Clamp Diagonal Movement / Clamp Camera Zoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my camera zoom in and out but I want to lock the amount in which it can zoom. I have tried a few things although they haven't achieved the outcome I was hoping for. My camera is sitting at a rotation of 65 degrees on the X axis and I want to move it along that diagonal axis. Thanks in advance!

```
Camera.main.transform.Translate(0,0, Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The code above zooms the camera in the way that I want although I am unsure how to clamp the values.

```
    cameraDistance += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    cameraDistance = Mathf.Clamp(cameraDistance, minCameraDistance, maxCameraDistance);
    Camera.main.transform.localPosition = (new Vector3(0, -cameraDistance, 0));
```

The code above clamps the value but only moves in an upwards direction

```
    cameraDistance += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    cameraDistance = Mathf.Clamp(cameraDistance, minCameraDistance, maxCameraDistance);
    Camera.main.fieldOfView = -cameraDistance;
```

The code above clamps the value and keeps my rotation focused on the player although it distorts the view to much.

> NOTE! I definitely don't want change my cameras field of view!

Comment: new Vector3(0, -cameraDistance, 0) is moving on the y axis but I gather you prefer it on the z axis? Try new Vector3(0, whateverHeightYouWant,  -cameraDistance)

Comment: @Absinthe thanks for the comment, that would work although then I would have to calculate the correct height as well and that was something I wasn't sure how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the first line of code that works, just add some more logic.

```
//Checks if camera is inside of bounds
if(Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) >= minCameraDistance &&
   Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) <= maxCameraDistance) {
    //Do Translation
    Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, 0, Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
else if (Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) < minCameraDistance) { //Checks if camera is too close to the target
    Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, 0, Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) - minCameraDistance + Mathf.Epsilon);
}
else if (Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) > maxCameraDistance) { //Check if the camera is too far from the target
    Camera.main.transform.Translate(0, 0, Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, targetObject.position) - maxCameraDistance + Mathf.Epsilon);
}
```

I added a targetObject(Transform variable) that represents the object from where the distance is calculated.

Change that to any object or Vector3 to pivot the camera. Ex: if it is the origin put `Vector3.zero` instead of `targetObject.position`

The two else if statements clamps the values so camera doesn't go too close or too far away from the `minCameraDistance` and `maxCameraDistance` values.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and explained extremely well!